# When using include, php adds "" to html

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I catch html from two files with javascript. In one of the files I include info to connect to my DB.

But when I do, php adds two " to my html. All files are saved with the encoding UTF8.

Index.php html

```
<div class="f-l" id="right-column"></div>
```

Javascript.js

```
 $('#lead, #prospects').change(function() {
        var kund_id = 'kund_id=' + $('#lead option:selected, #prospects option:selected').attr('value');
        $.post(
            'get_kund.php',
            kund_id,
            function(data){
                $('#center-column').html(data)
        });

        $.post(
            'get_kontaktperson.php',
            kund_id,
            function(data){
                $('#right-column').html(data)
        }); return false;
    });
```

get_kontaktperson.php

```
include("db_connect.php");
$kund_id = $_POST['kund_id'];
$qry = "SELECT * FROM kontaktperson WHERE kund_id='$kund_id' ORDER BY id DESC";
$result=mysql_query($qry);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))  {
echo 'some html'; }
```

db_connect.php

```
require_once('db_info_login.php');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if(!$link) {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' 

. mysql_error());
    }   
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
    if(!$db) {
        die('Unable to select database');
    }
    mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8')
```

This adds "" above the html code from get_kontaktperson.php:

[image]

Why this seems to be a problem for me, the `<div class="kontaktperson">` is missplaced by something. If I take away the include it will show the html content correct. But when I put in some data, this will occur. Margin on the right column...
[image]

Comment: You are **wide open** to SQL injection attacks, and **you will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Use prepared/parameterized queries with PDO or similar to avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: **you will be hacked**

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Ok, thanks. Will go over to PDO.

Answer (score 9):

Those two quotation marks are used by Chrome's web inspector to denote content inside the element. As there is no content, two quotation marks are shown without anything inside them.

Comment: Okey, thought that was the cause for one of my <div> to be missplaced.

Comment: I now updated some info, why I think this is the problem for me.

Comment: Hmm. jQuery might be inserting some tidbits, don't really know it well enough to tell for certain.

Comment: Try running a console.log on the `data` and seeing what that gives you.

Comment: 100% sure that it do not have anything with, html, css or jQuery to do. When I take away the DB connection the problem dissapears and my <div> will show properly.

Will se if the problem remains after switching to PDO, can't see any reason why it should change. But we will see, I'll update later.

Comment: The problem was that I used UTF-8 on all my files. The included ones had to be ANSI as UTF-8 aka UTF-8 without BOM.

So it was the BOM that added the extra top-margin. Thanks for your help guys.